# fgetc misses bytes while reading a file

Tags: c, fgetc

I use the function `fgetc` to read each byte of a file, and then write it with `printf`.

I just noticed that sometimes, `fgetc` just miss some bytes, when I compare my result with a hex editor.

For example, the first mistake starts around the 118th byte, and a lot of other mistakes randomly ...

Somebody ever experienced this?

This is the code (Windows)

```
char main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fdIn;
    FILE* fdOut;
    long size = 0;
    long i = 0;
    char c = 0;
    if (argc == 3) {
        if ((fdIn = fopen(argv[1], "rt")) == NULL) {
            printf("FAIL\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if ((fdOut = fopen(argv[2], "w+")) == NULL) {
            printf("FAIL\n");
            return 0;
        }
        fseek(fdIn, 0L, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fdIn);
        fseek(fdIn, 0L, 0);
        fprintf(fdOut, "unsigned char shellcode[%ld] = {", size);
        while (i < size) {
            c = fgetc(fdIn);
            if (!(i % 16))
                fprintf(fdOut, "\n\t");
            fprintf(fdOut, "0x%02X", (unsigned char)c);
            if (i != size - 1)
                fprintf(fdOut, ", ");
            i++;
        }
        fprintf(fdOut, "\n};\n");
        fclose(fdIn);
        fclose(fdOut);
        printf("SUCCESS");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Show us your code, your test data, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: Are you working on WIndows?  Are the missing characters CR (`\r`, `\012`)?  Or perhaps ^Z (`\032`)?  Did you open the file in text mode or binary mode?

Comment: It probably isn't fair to ask you, Adam (so this is really aimed at the world in general), but I'm left wondering: why do people insist on use `fgetc()` instead of `getc()`?  There is a strong tendency here on SO for novice questions to use `fgetc()` for single character output and to use `printf()` for all output, even when `putchar()` would do the job admirably.  Ah well, it's probably inscrutable — but it is odd to me.

Comment: That's not the complete code (`FILE` is undeclared).

Comment: `char` is the wrong return type for `main`.

Comment: `argv[1]` already is of type `char *`. Why cast it to `(char *)` again?

Comment: `fgetc` doesn't return `char` for a reason.

Comment: Congratulations: I've seen a lot of return types for `main()`, but I think this is the first time I've seen `char` used.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for more information.

Comment: Why open `fdOut` in read/write mode if you never read from it?

Comment: You could just output `unsigned char shellcode[] = {`; that way you don't need `size` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode.

```
// if ((fdIn = fopen((char*)argv[1], "rt")) == NULL) { 
//                                 >.< 
if ((fdIn = fopen((char*)argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
```

In text mode, and likely a Windows based machine given the `"rt"`, a `'\r'`, `'\n'` pair is certainly translated into `'\n'`.  IAC, no translations are needed for OP's goal of a hex dump.

---

2nd issue: `fgetc()` returns an `int` in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  Use type `int` to distinguish `EOF` from all data input.

```
// char c = 0;
int c = 0;
...
c = fgetc(fdIn);

// also add
if (c == EOF) break;
```

Comment: Note: Output file should remain opened in text mode as code is using `fprintf(fdOut, "0x%02X"` to print _text_.